# Is there any way to capture global key presses in Mac OS using Swift

Tags: macos, swift

Is there any way to capture global key presses (even when my application isn't active) in Mac OS using Swift?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use NSEvent to add a global event monitor. Checkout this Swift 3 example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40509620/1791525