# Listening for global keyboard shortcuts in MacOS application

Tags: swift3, keyboard-shortcuts, macos-sierra

I've created a small Swift app that lives in the menu bar (over by the clock).  I'd like to have the app listen for a keyboard shortcut when it's in the background and then have it make a call to a web API to get some information.  I have everything working except for the global keyboard shortcut part.

After some searching I came across `NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents`.  This initially looked promising.  I was able to get my app to receive all key presses and filter out everything except for the one I was looking for.  After some experimenting and confirmation from the Apple documentation I found out that this mechanism doesn't actually "handle" the event; the key press still gets sent to the foreground application which is undesirable in this case.

Is there a better/proper way to have my application respond to a global keyboard shortcut?  Ideally, this would be possible without the use of any 3rd party APIs or applications, though it's not a deal-breaker.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to listen to global hotkeys with Swift in a macOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28281653/how-to-listen-to-global-hotkeys-with-swift-in-a-macos-app)

Answer (score 2):

I made a [Swift package](https://github.com/sindresorhus/KeyboardShortcuts) that makes it super simple to add global keyboard shortcuts.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import KeyboardShortcuts

// Declare the shortcut for strongly-typed access
extension KeyboardShortcuts.Name {
    static let toggleUnicornMode = Self("toggleUnicornMode")
}

@main
final class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        // Register the listener
        KeyboardShortcuts.onKeyUp(for: .toggleUnicornMode) { [self] in
            isUnicornMode.toggle()
        }
    }
}

// You also need to let the user choose a shortcut in the preferences
struct PreferencesView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
            Text("Toggle Unicorn Mode:")
            KeyboardShortcuts.Recorder(for: .toggleUnicornMode)
        }
    }
}
```

*If you look at the [codebase](https://github.com/sindresorhus/KeyboardShortcuts/blob/main/Sources/KeyboardShortcuts/CarbonKeyboardShortcuts.swift) (a lot of archaic code needed), you'll realize why you don't want to implement this from scratch.*