# Global keyboard shortcuts for a Mac tray app

Tags: swift, macos

I am developing a Mac app using Swift 4 which only runs as an Agent (it only has a menu in the tray). I'm completely new to Swift.

I want it to respond to keyboard shortcuts, but the basic shortcuts (see picture) only work when the app has focus (in my case, when the menu is being clicked).

[image: screenshot]

So what I need is for my app to respond to system-wide keyboard shortcuts.

I've tried:

- [HotKey](https://github.com/soffes/HotKey) but it doesn't seem to be compatible with Swift 4, or perhaps I can't use Swift Package Manager
- [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29801216/2559950) but again Swift 4 raises several errors that I couldn't solve

Has anyone done it?

Comment: I don't specifically know how it's done in Swift, but years ago I wrote Objective-C code to do this: https://github.com/mdippery/blackout/blob/master/Source/BOApplication.m#L65 I haven't tested it on the latest OS but I think it still works.

Comment: I think HotKey uses similar APIs, so it probably still works. Anyway, I solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

So I ended up getting it to work with HotKey:

- by using Carthage as a package manager instead of SPM
- and by not using HotKey's example code from their README, which for some reason didn't work for me, but the one in their [example app](https://github.com/soffes/HotKey/blob/master/Example/Sources/ViewController.swift#L19).

It works great!

Comment: Did you ever release your app? Please post a link to it - looks interesting!

Comment: https://apps.apple.com/fr/app/pairprogram/id1323768897?mt=12 :)

Answer (score 5):

I made a [Swift package](https://github.com/sindresorhus/KeyboardShortcuts) that makes this very easy:

```swift
import KeyboardShortcuts

extension KeyboardShortcuts.Name {
    static let startFiveRounds = Self("startFiveRounds", default: .init(.t, modifiers: [.command, .option]))
}

@main
final class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        KeyboardShortcuts.onKeyUp(for: .startFiveRounds) {
            // …
        }
    }
}
```

Even though you already solved your problem, I think this could be useful for other people having the same problem.

I would also recommend letting the user pick their own keyboard shortcut instead of hardcoding it. My package comes with a control where the user can set their preferred shortcut.