# Monitor when app opens file

Tags: swift, appkit, nsevent

I am wondering if there is a way to monitor when a user presses open file (`cmd+o`) in any application.

I was thinking I could use [`addGlobalMonitorForEvents`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsevent/1535472-addglobalmonitorforevents), but I was not sure how to get the specific on "Open File..." event.

Comment: I hope this turns out to be impossible.

Comment: You can only monitor modifier keys (flags changed) when using global monitor. So you will be able to detect only if the user press the command key. There is no way to monitor key down events globally.

Comment: @LeoDabus what about alfred? It is able to monitor the key down events globally. https://www.alfredapp.com/

Comment: have u gone through the answer @pudility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to mostly solve the problem by using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28281653/how-to-listen-to-global-hotkeys-with-swift-in-an-os-x-app):

```
    let keycode = UInt16(0x1F)
    let keymask: NSEvent.ModifierFlags = NSEvent.ModifierFlags.command
    //...
    let options = NSDictionary(object: kCFBooleanTrue, forKey: kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt.takeUnretainedValue() as NSString) as CFDictionary
    let trusted = AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions(options)
    if (trusted) {
        NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: .keyUp, handler: self.handler)
    }
```