# SwiftUI: Passing a variable from Content View to a Class

Tags: swift, swiftui

In my menu bar macOS app, i'm trying to access a toggle that's in my Content View from my StatusBarController class. This switch is meant to keep the popover shown on screen even when a user clicks outside the app.

[image]

Content View

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var lock = false
    

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Hello World")
            Toggle( isOn: $lock, label: {
        })
        .toggleStyle(SwitchToggleStyle())
           
        }
       .frame(width: 360.0, height: 160.0, alignment: .top)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

StatusBarController

```
    class StatusBarController {
    private var eventMonitor: EventMonitor?
    private var content: ContentView?

        func unlockpopover() {
            eventMonitor = EventMonitor(mask: [.leftMouseDown, .rightMouseDown], handler: mouseEventHandler)
        }
 
        if lock {
                  // Popover window is locked if user clicks outside the app
                   }else {
                   unlockpopover() // Popover window is unlocked if user clicks outside the app
                
                  }                
             }    
      }
}
```

How do i access the 'lock' variable from Content View?

> 'Cannot find 'lock' in scope'

is the error that's currently showing.

[MenuBar project template](https://github.com/AnaghSharma/Ambar-SwiftUI) i'm using.

****EDIT****
@lorem ipsum's suggestion of using EnvironmentObject and observable object.

StatusBarController

```
class StatusBarController:ObservableObject {
    private var eventMonitor: EventMonitor?
    private var content: ContentView?

    @Published var lock: Bool = false

        func unlockpopover() {
            eventMonitor = EventMonitor(mask: [.leftMouseDown, .rightMouseDown], handler: mouseEventHandler)
        }
 
        if lock {
                  // Popover window is locked if user clicks outside the app
                   }else {
                   unlockpopover() // Popover window is unlocked if user clicks outside the app
                
                  }                
             }    
      }
}
```

Content View

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var test: StatusBarController
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Hello World")
            Toggle( isOn: $test.lock, label: {
        })
        .toggleStyle(SwitchToggleStyle())
        }
       .environmentObject(self.test)
       .frame(width: 360.0, height: 160.0, alignment: .top)
    }
}
```

App crashes with this error highlighted on $test.lock

> Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type StatusBarController
> found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for StatusBarController may be
> missing as an ancestor of this view.

AppDelegate

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var popover = NSPopover.init()
    var statusBar: StatusBarController?

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the contents
        let contentView = ContentView()

        // Set the SwiftUI's ContentView to the Popover's ContentViewController
        popover.contentViewController = MainViewController()
        popover.contentSize = NSSize(width: 360, height: 360)
        popover.contentViewController?.view = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView)     
        // Create the Status Bar Item with the Popover
        statusBar = StatusBarController.init(popover)

    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }
}
```

Comment: Make your `StatusBarController` and `ObservableObject` and share it with your `ContentView` as an `@EnvironmentObject` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentobject

Comment: Thanks for responding! I tried out your suggestion. I'm getting "Cannot convert value of type 'Published.Publisher' to expected argument type 'Binding'. Look at my updated question.

Comment: You should be using `$test.lock` maybe that is the issue.

Comment: That fixed it but it's now crashing with this error highlighted on $test.lock "Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type StatusBarController found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for StatusBarController may be missing as an ancestor of this view."

Comment: You need to pass the environment object when you create the content view. Something like ContentView().environmentObject(statusBarController)

Comment: I've tried that and now i get this error "Type 'StatusBarController.Type' cannot conform to 'ObservableObject'"

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. Notice the the lower case you have to pass the actual controller not just write StatusBarController

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68239237/swiftui-invoke-nspopover-with-keyboard-shortcut